# What mysql client to run with Rails / Mac OS X?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to learn how to use mysql with a rails app. I installed mysql with Homebrew (brew install mysql), and I don't understand how to run a mysql server or client (what that means, entails, or anything).

My OS is Mac OS Snow Leopard.

How do I run a mysql server or client? I just want to get something functioning so I can do rake db:create, create my development database, and get my app up and running so I can create models, tables, and essentially develop without hassle.

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run mysqld in terminal, that should do it. As:

```
$ mysqld
```

Comment: [mxcl/homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) is a great package manager through which to install mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You could install mysql using the installer http://mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads
That includes a settings app for start/stop and an autorunner, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The default for starting your mysqlserver is `mysql.server start`. This will create a socket at: `/tmp/mysql.sock`

A [example config](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database) for a development mysql database would be (defined in `database.yml`):

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: rails_app_development
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

You will need to include the mysql2 gem in your Gemfile: `gem 'mysql2'`

For setting up a fast development environment it is fine to just go with sqlite3 and sort the connection with another database later.

I can recommend the [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) editor for connecting to your DB and viewing the data and create/edit/remove of databases and objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Server: http://mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads

Client: http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

After install it you will find start/stop controls in OS X System Preferences